Python KeyError Even Though Dictionary Contains Value
I am implementing the wave function collapse algorithm in Python, and I have tiles and rule sets for each tile. To store the rule sets, I have a createAll function which is a dictionary of a tile ands its rules.
This is the createAll function (inside TileRuleSetFactory):
    @staticmethod
    def createAll() -> dict[Tile, TileRuleSet]:
        if (TileRuleSetFactory._allRuleSets != None):
            return TileRuleSetFactory._allRuleSets
        
        ruleSets: dict[Tile, TileRuleSet] = {}

        ruleSets[TileFactory.createBlank()] = TileRuleSetFactory.createBlank()
        print(ruleSets)
        print(ruleSets[TileFactory.createBlank()])
        ruleSets[TileFactory.createUp()] = TileRuleSetFactory.createUp()
        ruleSets[TileFactory.createRight()] = TileRuleSetFactory.createRight()
        ruleSets[TileFactory.createDown()] = TileRuleSetFactory.createDown()
        ruleSets[TileFactory.createLeft()] = TileRuleSetFactory.createLeft()

        TileRuleSetFactory._allRuleSets = ruleSets

        return ruleSets

the TileFactory class:
class TileFactory:
    #region Tile IDs
    MAX_ID = 4

    BLANK_ID: int = 0
    UP_ID: int = 1
    RIGHT_ID: int = 2
    DOWN_ID: int = 3
    LEFT_ID: int = 4
    #endregion

    # for flyweight pattern
    _createdTiles: dict[int, Tile] = {}

    @staticmethod
    def createAllTiles() -> list[Tile]:
        tiles: list[Tile] = []

        tiles.append(TileFactory.createBlank())
        tiles.append(TileFactory.createUp())
        tiles.append(TileFactory.createRight())
        tiles.append(TileFactory.createDown())
        tiles.append(TileFactory.createLeft())

        return tiles

    @staticmethod
    def createRandTile() -> Tile:
        return TileFactory.createById(randint(0, TileFactory.MAX_ID))

    @staticmethod
    def createById(id: int) -> Tile:
        if (id == TileFactory.BLANK_ID):
            return TileFactory.createBlank()
        
        if (id == TileFactory.UP_ID):
            return TileFactory.createUp()
        
        if (id == TileFactory.RIGHT_ID):
            return TileFactory.createRight()
        
        if (id == TileFactory.DOWN_ID):
            return TileFactory.createDown()
        
        if (id == TileFactory.LEFT_ID):
            return TileFactory.createLeft()
        
        else:
            raise ValueError()

    @staticmethod
    def createBlank() -> Tile:
        return TileFactory._createdTiles.get(TileFactory.BLANK_ID, Tile('./tiles/blank.png'))
    
    @staticmethod
    def createUp() -> Tile:
        return TileFactory._createdTiles.get(TileFactory.UP_ID, Tile('./tiles/up.png'))
    
    @staticmethod
    def createRight() -> Tile:
        return TileFactory._createdTiles.get(TileFactory.RIGHT_ID, Tile('./tiles/right.png'))
    
    @staticmethod
    def createDown() -> Tile:
        return TileFactory._createdTiles.get(TileFactory.DOWN_ID, Tile('./tiles/down.png'))
    
    @staticmethod
    def createLeft() -> Tile:
        return TileFactory._createdTiles.get(TileFactory.LEFT_ID, Tile('./tiles/left.png'))

the Tile class:
class Tile:
    def __init__(self, imgPath: str) -> None:
        self.img: pygame.Surface = pygame.image.load(imgPath)
        self.imgPath = imgPath

    def __eq__(self, value: object) -> bool:
        if (type(value) != Tile):
            return False
        
        return self.img == value.img
    
    def __hash__(self) -> int:
        return self.imgPath.__hash__()
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return str(self.__hash__())
    
    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return self.__str__()

and the TileRuleSet class:
class TileRuleSet:
    def __init__(self, up: set[Tile] = set(),
                 right: set[Tile] = set(), down: set[Tile] = set(), left: set[Tile] = set()) -> None:
        self.up: set[Tile] = up
        self.right: set[Tile] = right
        self.down: set[Tile] = down
        self.left: set[Tile] = left

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"UP: {setToString(self.up)}, RIGHT: {setToString(self.right)}, "\
        f"DOWN: {setToString(self.down)}, LEFT: {setToString(self.left)}\n"
    
    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return self.__str__()

However, when I call the static createAll method, the following prints in the console:
{238499618696605147: UP: {4114546419569344162, 238499618696605147}, RIGHT: {-6386996300615071302, 238499618696605147}, DOWN: {238499618696605147, 6516502529729026507}, LEFT: {-848466221319434871, 238499618696605147}
}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[PATH]\tile.py", line 221, in <module>
    TileRuleSetFactory.createAll()
  File "[PATH]\tile.py", line 136, in createAll
    print(ruleSets[TileFactory.createBlank()])
          ~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 238499618696605147

As you can see, the hash value of 238499618696605147 is present in the dictionary, but I'm still getting a KeyError. Why is this happening, and how do I fix it?

Your Tile objects are comparing two pygame.Surface objects for equality, which may or may not be defined in any useful way.  Compare self.imgPath and value.imgPath instead - after all, that's what the __hash__() of these objects is calculated from, and dicts require that their keys have consistent notions of hashing and equality.

Try using .get() method of dict, in this case it will return false if the key returned from TileFactory.createBlank() does not exist in RuleSets, and now, it is possible to validate the behavior, if you don't have the key.
ex:
if rule_set_value := ruleSets.get(TileFactory.createBlank()):
    print(rule_set_value)
else:
    #do something

And if is a set, try to validate use in:
if TileFactory.createBlank() in ruleSets:
    print(ruleSets[TileFactory.createBlank()])

